# Move e-mails by senderemailaddress outlook macro

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to move some messages from Inbox to a `subfolder` but this code (that I have copied from other forum) is not working. Can you tell me what is going wrong? Do you think it is not working because of the fact that I have two different accounts in this Outlook?

---

```
Public Sub Move_Items()
   '// Declare your Variables
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim lngCount As Long

    On Error GoTo MsgErr
    Set Inbox Reference
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Set Items = Inbox.Items

   '// Loop through the Items in the folder backwards
    For lngCount = Inbox.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Item = Inbox.Items.Item(lngCount)

        If Item.Class = olMail Then
            Select Case Item.SenderEmailAddress

               '// Email_One
                Case "bb"
                   // Set SubFolder of Inbox
                    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("BB")
                    Set Item = Items.Find("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'bb@gmail.com'")
                    If TypeName(Item) <> "Nothing" Then
                       // Mark As Read
                        Item.UnRead = False
                       // Move Mail Item to sub Folder
                        Item.Move SubFolder
                    End If

              '// Email_Two
                Case "aa"
                   '// Set SubFolder of Inbox
                    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("AA")
                    Set Item = Items.Find("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'aa@gmail.com'")
                    If TypeName(Item) <> "Nothing" Then
                       '// Mark As Read
                        Item.UnRead = False
                       '// Move Mail Item to sub Folder
                        Item.Move SubFolder
                    End If

                Case Else:
                    Exit Sub
            End Select
        End If
    Next lngCount

MsgErr_Exit:
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set Items = Nothing

    Exit Sub

'// Error information
MsgErr:
    MsgBox "An unexpected Error has occurred." _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
         , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume MsgErr_Exit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Select Case is not set correctly-

`Case "bb"` should be `Case "bb@gmail.com"` & `Case "aa"` should be `Case "aa@gmail.com"`

also `Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("BB")` `BB` should be your subfolder name

__

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Move_Items()
   '// Declare your Variables
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder '<- has been added
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim lngCount As Long

'    On Error GoTo MsgErr
   '// Set Inbox Reference
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Folder = Application.Session.PickFolder
    Set Items = Inbox.Items

   '// Loop through the Items in the folder backwards
    For lngCount = Inbox.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Item = Inbox.Items.Item(lngCount)

        Debug.Print Item.Subject

        If Item.Class = olMail Then
            Select Case Item.SenderEmailAddress

'               // Email_One
                Case "bb@gmail.com"
'                   // Set SubFolder of Inbox
                    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Temp")
                    Set Item = Items.Find("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'bb@gmail.com'")
                    If TypeName(Item) <> "Nothing" Then
'                       // Mark As Read
                        Item.UnRead = False
'                       // Move Mail Item to sub Folder
                        Item.Move SubFolder
                    End If

'               // Email_Two
                Case "aa@gmail.com"
'                   // Set SubFolder of Inbox
                    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Temp")
                    Set Item = Items.Find("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'aa@gmail.com'")
                    If TypeName(Item) <> "Nothing" Then
'                       // Mark As Read
                        Item.UnRead = False
'                       // Move Mail Item to sub Folder
                        Item.Move SubFolder
                    End If

            End Select
        End If
    Next lngCount

MsgErr_Exit:
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set Items = Nothing

    Exit Sub

'// Error information
MsgErr:
    MsgBox "An unexpected Error has occurred." _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
         , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume MsgErr_Exit
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Om3r, thank you for helping. It still does not work... Do you think it is because I have two accounts in this outlook?

Comment: yes I view the inbox of one of the accounts while running the code. There are no errors but no results either... :(