# Organise e-mails by domain; move into @sender.com folder

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to get my head around how I would write an inbox to maintain an inbox with subfolders listed by domain e.g. :

```
Inbox->@client1.com->client1 e-mails
```

I had a poke around on here and this is close to what I'm trying to get at:
[Move e-mails by senderemailaddress outlook macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200110/move-e-mails-by-senderemailaddress-outlook-macro/37200554#37200554)

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Move_Items()
   '// Declare your Variables
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder '<- has been added
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim lngCount As Long

'    On Error GoTo MsgErr
   '// Set Inbox Reference
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Folder = Application.Session.PickFolder
    Set Items = Inbox.Items

   '// Loop through the Items in the folder backwards
    For lngCount = Inbox.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Item = Inbox.Items.Item(lngCount)

        Debug.Print Item.Subject

        If Item.Class = olMail Then
            Select Case Item.SenderEmailAddress

'               // Email_One
                Case "bb@gmail.com"
'                   // Set SubFolder of Inbox
                    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Temp")
                    Set Item = Items.Find("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'bb@gmail.com'")
                    If TypeName(Item) <> "Nothing" Then
'                       // Mark As Read
                        Item.UnRead = False
'                       // Move Mail Item to sub Folder
                        Item.Move SubFolder
                    End If

'               // Email_Two
                Case "aa@gmail.com"
'                   // Set SubFolder of Inbox
                    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Temp")
                    Set Item = Items.Find("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'aa@gmail.com'")
                    If TypeName(Item) <> "Nothing" Then
'                       // Mark As Read
                        Item.UnRead = False
'                       // Move Mail Item to sub Folder
                        Item.Move SubFolder
                    End If

            End Select
        End If
    Next lngCount

MsgErr_Exit:
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set Items = Nothing

    Exit Sub

'// Error information
MsgErr:
    MsgBox "An unexpected Error has occurred." _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
         , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume MsgErr_Exit
End Sub
```

What it is missing is the automation piece however, I'm looking for a "run and file" approach where it checks if the subfolder exists. (e.g. @client1.com)

If the subfolder does exist and the domain matches, move the e-mail there. If it does not, create new subfolder for the client with a new domain and file it in there.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use ***[Right](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxs6hz0a(v=vs.90).aspx)*** - ***[Len](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxsw58z6(v=vs.90).aspx)*** - ***[Instr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx)*** and ***[Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx)*** Function

---

Example

```
Dim FolderName As String
FolderName = Right("bb@gmail.com", _
               Len("bb@gmail.com") _
           - InStr("bb@gmail.com", "@"))

Debug.Print FolderName 'Immediate Window prints gmail.com

FolderName = "@" & FolderName

Debug.Print FolderName 'Immediate Window prints @gmail.com
```

---

Once you have **`FolderName`** then check if folder Exists or else create one

---

```
If FolderExists(Inbox, FolderName) = True Then
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(FolderName)
Else
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders.Add(FolderName)
End If

'//  Function - Check folder Exist
Private Function FolderExists(Inbox As MAPIFolder, FolderName As String)
    Dim Sub_Folder As MAPIFolder

    On Error GoTo Exit_Err
    Set Sub_Folder = Inbox.Folders(FolderName)

    FolderExists = True
        Exit Function

Exit_Err:
    FolderExists = False

End Function
```

---

Your code should look like

---

```
        If Item.Class = olMail Then
            Select Case Item.SenderEmailAddress

'               // Email_One
                Case "bb@gmail.com"

'                   // Set SubFolder of Inbox
                Dim FolderName As String
                FolderName = Right("bb@gmail.com", _
                               Len("bb@gmail.com") _
                           - InStr("bb@gmail.com", "@"))

                Debug.Print FolderName 'Immediate Window prints gmail.com

                FolderName = "@" & FolderName

                Debug.Print FolderName 'Immediate Window prints @gmail.com

                '// Check if folder exist else create one
                If FolderExists(Inbox, FolderName) = True Then
                    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(FolderName)
                Else
                    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders.Add(FolderName)
                End If
```

---

Add your **`Private Function FolderExists`** after **`End Sub`**